# Can't rename folder after creation a new file inside

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.io.file

When I create new folder in filesystem and new empty index.html file inside with ASP.NET Core application by `File.Create(indexFilePath)` or by `FileInfo`'s object `Create()` method, it is impossible to delete or rename this folder for some long period of time.

If I try to do it in application, I get an IOException: **Access to the path 'D:\Temp\Delete_test5' is denied.**

If I try to delete it manually, I get warning window with message: **The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program**.

If I try to delete an inner file manually, I get warning window with message: **The action can't be completed because the file is open in iisexpress.exe**

How to delete/rename the folder after creating in this case?

**Edited:**

There is a code for file generation:

```
public static void CreateIndexHtmlFile(string folderPath)
{
    string indexFilePath = (folderPath.EndsWith(@"\") ? folderPath : folderPath + @"\") + "index.html";

    //if (Directory.Exists(folderPath) && !File.Exists(indexFilePath))
    //{
    //    File.Create(indexFilePath);
    //}

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(indexFilePath);

    if (dir.Exists && !file.Exists)
    {
        file.Create();
    }
}
```

both `File.Create(indexFilePath);` and `file.Create();` bring the same problem. `file` have no methods like `Dispose` or `Close`

Comment: Did you close the file after creating it (and before renaming the folder)?

Comment: You need to show us your code, otherwise, we cannot help.

Comment: Most likely, you have an open handle to a file in that folder.  Make sure you close and Dispose the file you create.  If you have an open file handle for a file in a folder, the OS will limit what you can do to the folder

Comment: You've only shown partial code, we still can't test.

Comment: `File.Create` and `FileInfo.Create` create a `FileStream`, which you have left open and will need to be disposed.

Comment: you need to dispose of the resource, look at the comment by @Scrobi Using statement should help out here